# Which is official open xml sdk nuget repo: DocumentFormat.OpenXml or Open-XML-SDK?

Tags: c#, nuget, openxml-sdk

Googling `Open XML SDK nuget` gives two results in the first page:

1. [DocumentFormat.OpenXml](https://www.nuget.org/packages/DocumentFormat.OpenXml/)
2. [Open-XML-SDK](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Open-XML-SDK/)

Both seems quite actively updated, and even the descriptions are exactly the same! But it seems the former has significantly more downloads.
Could anyone explain a little which one to choose, and why there are two repos?

Comment: If you click on the Project Site, both will redirect to [this GitHub repository](https://github.com/OfficeDev/Open-XML-SDK), this repository has a link in the "About" section to [this nuget page](https://www.nuget.org/packages/DocumentFormat.OpenXml/). You can also see that by the owner, of one of them is Microsoft

Comment: thanks. i see the owners diff. but both author is mircosoft. and in visual studio nuget package only displays author...

Comment: The other repo is probably a fork, and the fork author must have kept the original author.

Comment: It looks like an effective rename of the package.  Note that Open-XML-SDK has not been updated since 2.9.1 which was around 3 yrs ago at this point.  The rename happened somewhere longer ago than that, and it looks to me like they continued to maintain under the older package name for a while.